# Is it reasonable to assume there is a function $f:R^2 \to [0,1]^2$ associated with the unit circle that represents Euclidean distance from the centre?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces

The Minkowski distance of order p between two points

$X=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}){\text{ and }}Y=(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots ,y_{n})\in {\mathbb  {R}}^{n}$

is defined as:

${\displaystyle D\left(X,Y\right)=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}} \tag{1}$

---

simplified, let p = 2, and then

${\displaystyle D\left(X,Y\right)=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}} \tag{2}$

I am trying to construct a connection between equation_2 and this figure that comes from the same [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance).

[image]

Where, the unit circle and x-axis cross at point (1,0) (ignored other crosses)

the Minkowski distance with $p=2$ corresponds to the Euclidean distance, and the point (1,0) is at the unit distance from the centre, so do other point at the unit circle.

Let $X=(x_{1},x_{2})\in {\mathbb  {R}}^{2}$, Y = (0,0)

the points at the unit circle could be viewed as a bound, inside which, X was mapped from $R^2$ to $[0,1]^2$ (I am not sure if I use the notation, please feel free to fix it).

Is my understanding right?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The unit "circle" with respect to the Minkowski metric is $\{X \mid D(X, (0, 0)) = 1\}$ and when $p = 2$, it really is a circle as shown in the figure. I don't see what you mean by "$X$ was mapped from $R^2$ to $[0, 1]^2$. The restriction of the function $f(X) = D(X, (0, 0))$ to the unit disc is a map from the unit disc to the unit interval $[0, 1]$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @RobArthan Your comments is helping me get a more clear mind. Actually I am asking the definition of the function $\{X \mid D(X, (0, 0)) = 1\}$ in the form of Arrow notation, things like ${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\operatorname {sqr} \colon X&\to X\\x&\mapsto x\cdot x,\end{aligned}}}$